# Sharepoint Online: Search Results Found But Not Displaying

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, display-template, search-results-webpart

I have set up a search results web part on the home page of a Sharepoint Online site I'm working on. I've set it up to use the Local People Results source, and the query being used is

```
{SearchBoxQuery} contentclass:spspeople
```

This is able to find all the profiles in our Sharepoint, but on the results web part, it's not displaying anything. It does show that it found things, however.

[image: Sharepoint Results]

It is using result type rules to display items, nothing custom on the template side. Is there something else I need to turn on or configure for the results to display properly?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, I found that I needed to make sure that show Ranked Results was checked, under Web Part Properties > Settings > Show ranked results